# li:hover issue on chrome browser

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am using a third party menu plugin on my page which opens submenus on hover over main items.On FF browser it seems to work fine,however on chrome the submenu doesn't shows up on desired location(Please refer to screenshot attached).The most weird part is this remains only for while,after spending some time on that page it shows up properly.

Is this a browser problem?

**CSS to display the submenu**

```
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
top: 52px;
left: 0;
opacity: 1;
}
```

[image: Menu on hover issue on chrome]

Comment: from that what I can see is you need to apply higher z-index.....

Comment: Show us your code. Image tells us nothing.

Comment: Instead of using top you can use margin-top

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more line of css for Chrome browser and set value of `-webkit-top` as per your requirement. I was facing same issue for chrome and ie but it has been solved by using `-webkit-` and `-ie-` respectively for chrome and ie.

Like this :

```
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
top: 52px;
left: 0;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-top:12px;
}
```

Comment: seems like browser is taking some time to put submenu in right place.

Comment: Can u plz upload your source code on JSFiddle or here. So that we can solve it directly and see whether it's working for you or not. @Tweety01

Answer (score 0):

try adding :

```
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
```